# Why the users are not clicking on the button?

Tags: conversion, conversion-rate

Ok, this questions might sound stupid.

I work on an internet start up, and we used to be a normal job posting board. But we have pivoted to a marketplace where the company can hire the candidate through our product, no paper work, neither for the company nor the candidate. The candidates can sign the contract on the app. Every thing is manage on the app.

But we are struggling to make the companies understand they can hire the candidate on the app and that there are many benefits by doing so.

So the process right now is basically the following:

1. Company post the job
2. We take them to a CRM with a list of recommended candidates (actions: shortlist, reject, message, view profile and some filters)
3. On the candidate profile view we have the same actions that are one the list plus **the famous button "Request to hire" or "Send job offer"** (we have tested many copies)
4. Companies normally shortlist candidates
5. Chat with candidates
6. Interview them

And for us is really important that after the interview if they have liked the candidate they come back to the app and click on the "Send job offer button"

Why is this not happening?

I will be grateful with any new ideas

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's an issue with the button as much as it is a significant modification to the company's normal workflow. Have you talked with any of your clients to see if they are aware of the feature and simply prefer to stick to their normal process?

Comment: Sorry, but there's a lot of information missing, we can only guess and probably add more noise than help you. I'd try what @maxathousand suggests, then go from there

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any particular reason, from their perspective, for the company to come back to your website to click that button; they've already interviewed the candidate, so they're already in contact, so if they want to make an offer they'll do it directly.

Comment: Daniel Beck is right and I wonder why that last button is so important. If it is because you can bill the company for every job offer I'm not surprised they are not clicking it!

Comment: A screen grab of the actual interface would be useful to look at

Comment: Here there is an screenshot 
[Screenshot 2016-12-13 18.21.20.png](https://postimg.org/image/dubrtbrp3/)

Comment: As others have mentioned, as a company, what incentive would I have to go back to the app and click the button?  As you wrote, I've already left your app while I'm interviewing the candidate.  The question is not "why is this not happening?" It's "why should it happen?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is not happening because **they are doing it behind the app**.

Companies are probably using the app:

- To get a filtered list from a big amount of candidates they probably have. So it is useful to them to get that part of the process ordered by the app.
- To get the job offer to a better/appropriate market of candidates.

If they get out of the process in your final step it is possibly because they were not looking for that in the app. This could be either:

- They don't know the benefits (or really know/understand them)
- They know the benefits but prefer not to use them.

The case of your question is probably the second. And this seems not like a matter of UI but a matter of marketing and goals. **Maybe most companies don't really need those benefits**. Maybe some companies could need them, I can think of small ones. So there probably needs to be done some research about that part of the app, which might need some changes in your goals, classification of company types or some "re-education" on the way companies use the app.

Answer (score 2):

Companies large enough to have a human resource department will have their own policies on how to extend an offer of employment. Using your app probably ***violate those policies***.

The people using your app may have no control over those policies. You need to either market to smaller business or market directly to a business's H/R department and ask that they require their supervisors use your app.

Comment: Our business is market to small business and temporary employment

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the wording? How would a user know what will happen if she clicks a button labeled "Send job offer"?

Making a job offer is a big commitment. It's not something done lightly by clicking a button.

However, if, as you note, this is for more routine hiring of temporary, non-skilled labor by small businesses, it could be a benefit. Perhaps users are not thinking of returning to the site to use the rest of the service.

If you schedule the interview through the application, maybe send the user an email immediately after (or right before) the interview with a deep link to "Begin the hiring process for this candidate."

At any rate, I would begin with user testing sessions where you ask the user what they expect to happen when clicking any of the options. This would help to uncover reasons for their hesitation to hire through the app.

Answer (score 1):

Users are on your site to accomplish certain tasks. Maybe users aren't clicking the button because it doesn't look like it will help them complete the task they're working on at the time.

Maybe the user's task is to make an offer but the button's label isn't clear that it will help with that. (You're experimenting with other labels, so that's probably not the problem.)

The alternative is that users are working on tasks that don't include making an offer. Maybe users aren't ready to make an offer while they're looking at this page, but they'll be ready later. (Put the Offer button on that later page.)

Or, as others have pointed out, users might be on your site without a "make an offer" task at all. They're there purely to do research, then make offers through their own procedures.

Some contextual observations of people using the system (not a generic usability test, but a contextual inquiry) will shed some light on why they're doing what they do.

Answer (score 0):

I would think offering a candicate is quite a private process, or at least it has been made to be currently, an exchange of benefits, personal identifying data, and company private information may happen in the process, it seems kind of scary to let a third party be involved in this process.

Comment: Mmmmmm ........ I'd say a massive number of people and companies use this kind of services for online work. Even the site you're in!

Comment: do they really get involved in the offering stage?

Comment: of course, that's how they make money! Really, we're talking about a multi-billion dollar industry, check UpWork, Freelancer, Hubstaff, Outsourcely, Stack Exchange Careers and the likes